# Gathering columns with unequal length with same name in R

Tags: r

I want to gather data from experiments from data frame into columns. Data is in the following form;

[image]

and I want to arrange data in the format given below;

[image]

Is there any simple method available to do it in R/RStudio? I tried tidyr, rbind and cbind as suggested in different examples. But I am unable to do ad found that these are not much relevant.
It will be great if someone help me to understand.

Thanks

Comment: Hello dear Sadaf. It would be great if you could share a reproducible data or a small excerpt of your data set.

Comment: Additionally, figuring out which method to use would be helped if we knew what you wanted to ultimately do with the second data format.

Comment: @SleepyMiles, the data is of different runs from an experiment. I want to see that how the variables will finally evolve, trying to make plots of Z-scores or some time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a similar data set and applied the following code based on binding since you mentioned it in your question, it may sound verbose but it gets you to the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  runs = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  col1 = c(3, 4, 5, 5),
  col2 = c(5, 3, 1, 4), 
  col3 = c(6, 4, 9, 2),
  col1 = c(0, 2, 2, 1),
  col2 = c(2, 3, 1, 7), 
  col3 = c(2, 4, 9, 9),
  col1 = c(3, 4, 5, 7),
  col2 = c(3, 3, 1, 4), 
  col3 = c(3, 2, NA, NA), .name_repair = "minimal")

df %>%
  select(2:4) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>%
              select(5:7)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              select(8:10)) %>%
  select(run, col1:col3)
```

Ok there are two other ways I thought you might be interested to know, since it was your question. These are not my codes completely and I got help for that but there are great alternative ways of dealing with the same problem:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"), names_to = c(".value")) %>% # Pay attention to the `.value` sentinel it indicates that component of the name defines the name of the column containing the cell values, overriding values_to.
  group_by(runs) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
    runs  col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3     5     6
 2     2     4     3     4
 3     3     5     1     9
 4     4     5     4     2
 5     1     0     2     2
 6     2     2     3     4
 7     3     2     1     9
 8     4     1     7     9
 9     1     3     3     3
10     2     4     3     2
11     3     5     1    NA
12     4     7     4    NA
```

The above code is proposed by [@ Ashley G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11717004/ashley-g) which was amazing.
And the base R alternative:

```
data.frame(df$runs, 
           sapply(split.default(df[-1], names(df)[-1]), unlist),
           row.names = NULL)

   df.runs col1 col2 col3     # Here `split.default` splits the columns of data frame whereas `split` splits the rows.
1        1    3    5    6
2        2    4    3    4
3        3    5    1    9
4        4    5    4    2
5        1    0    2    2
6        2    2    3    4
7        3    2    1    9
8        4    1    7    9
9        1    3    3    3
10       2    4    3    2
11       3    5    1   NA
12       4    7    4   NA
```

The base R code is written by @[Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah), for which I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` function `melt` with `patterns` in `measure.vars`, you can try the following:

```
library(data.table)
#Some data in the same format as you have
df <- read.table(text="
1 0.8525099 0.5598105 0.4242143 0 0.06016425 0.678719492 0.4852765  0.4970301 0.1657070
2 0.1237982 0.2853534 0.8281460 0.42586728 0.31214568 0.647306659 0.5445816  0.4250520 0.9975251
3 0.4907858 0.4925835 0.6689135 0.06042183 0.47391134 0.002571686 0.5267215  0.4291427 NA
4 0.8524778 0.1091856 0.6529887 0.24606198 0.44869099 0.540201766 0.6263992  0.1448730 NA
")
#assigning names to columns
colnames(df) <- c("Run", rep(c("Logging", "Salinity","surface"),3))
setDT(df) #converting df into a data.table

df #Similar as your initial data frame
   Run   Logging  Salinity   surface    Logging   Salinity     surface   Logging  Salinity   surface
1:   1 0.8525099 0.5598105 0.4242143 0.00000000 0.06016425 0.678719492 0.4852765 0.4970301 0.1657070
2:   2 0.1237982 0.2853534 0.8281460 0.42586728 0.31214568 0.647306659 0.5445816 0.4250520 0.9975251
3:   3 0.4907858 0.4925835 0.6689135 0.06042183 0.47391134 0.002571686 0.5267215 0.4291427        NA
4:   4 0.8524778 0.1091856 0.6529887 0.24606198 0.44869099 0.540201766 0.6263992 0.1448730        NA

df2 <- melt(df, #melting data, converting from wide to long
        id.vars = 1, # here we attempt to fix the first column "Runs"
        measure.vars = patterns(Logging="Logging", # here we look up for a pattern of column names to convert into measure
                                Salinity= "Salinity",
                                surface="surface")
        )


#Output
df2
    Run variable    Logging   Salinity     surface
 1:   1        1 0.85250990 0.55981050 0.424214300
 2:   2        1 0.12379820 0.28535340 0.828146000
 3:   3        1 0.49078580 0.49258350 0.668913500
 4:   4        1 0.85247780 0.10918560 0.652988700
 5:   1        2 0.00000000 0.06016425 0.678719492
 6:   2        2 0.42586728 0.31214568 0.647306659
 7:   3        2 0.06042183 0.47391134 0.002571686
 8:   4        2 0.24606198 0.44869099 0.540201766
 9:   1        3 0.48527650 0.49703010 0.165707000
10:   2        3 0.54458160 0.42505200 0.997525100
11:   3        3 0.52672150 0.42914270          NA
12:   4        3 0.62639920 0.14487300          NA
```

And finally remove column `variable`

```
#Removing column variable (second column in df2) you get your result
df2[, -2]
    Run    Logging   Salinity     surface
 1:   1 0.85250990 0.55981050 0.424214300
 2:   2 0.12379820 0.28535340 0.828146000
 3:   3 0.49078580 0.49258350 0.668913500
 4:   4 0.85247780 0.10918560 0.652988700
 5:   1 0.00000000 0.06016425 0.678719492
 6:   2 0.42586728 0.31214568 0.647306659
 7:   3 0.06042183 0.47391134 0.002571686
 8:   4 0.24606198 0.44869099 0.540201766
 9:   1 0.48527650 0.49703010 0.165707000
10:   2 0.54458160 0.42505200 0.997525100
11:   3 0.52672150 0.42914270          NA
12:   4 0.62639920 0.14487300          NA
```

Comment: Sure @Sadaf, your question is interesting, just try next time to include your data sample as part of your question. Best!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Using @Chriss Paul's data.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -Run, names_to = '.value')

#     Run Logging Salinity  surface
#   <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1  0.853    0.560   0.424  
# 2     1  0        0.0602  0.679  
# 3     1  0.485    0.497   0.166  
# 4     2  0.124    0.285   0.828  
# 5     2  0.426    0.312   0.647  
# 6     2  0.545    0.425   0.998  
# 7     3  0.491    0.493   0.669  
# 8     3  0.0604   0.474   0.00257
# 9     3  0.527    0.429  NA      
#10     4  0.852    0.109   0.653  
#11     4  0.246    0.449   0.540  
#12     4  0.626    0.145  NA
```

PS - It is not advised to have data with duplicate column names.

Comment: Totally agree @Ronak Shah. Actually I had to force the names since initially R made them different when reading. I just wanted to be as closest as possible to Sadaf's question.